# Alternative to WhitePages API?

Tags: json, ajax, xml

I'm using the WhitePages API (developer.whitepages.com) to get a phone type (landline or cellular) and the phone's service provider (Verizon, T-Mobile, etc), but they only have a personal API which limits you to 2 calls a second and/or 1,500 calls a day. The paid version, or "Pro", is a minimum of $500 a month and/or $0.10 a call.

Does anyone know another service where I can get that information for free or cheaper than $500 / $0.10 a call? If not I'll have to try to cache everything and it'll technically be against their TOS...

Answer (score 0):

We've tried using NetNumber and TargusInfo. Maybe you want to look at them. Not sure how much they cost though.

How much volume are you trying to do?

Comment: I'm not sure, but there has to be more than 2 queries a second as the WhitePages API. The two you sent ill look into but they both have closed off APIs and i have to request quotes... probably spendy :\

Comment: haha, i'd say most good web services are. Google(+ all products), Apache, jQuery, Twitter API, Mozilla/WebKit/etc :). If you are counting just APIs, still, look at the ones Google, Twitter, and more have released, thats why I thought for sure, SOMEONE has haha

Comment: @OscarGodson -- You are right. Whitepages Pro APIs does support much higher QPS. Shouldn't be a problem! Disclaimer - I am at Whitepages.