# Possible solutions to crawl Whitepages

Tags: database, api

I am at the beginning stages of a program I have to write that will take users from a large database that I have and compare it against anything similar to Whitepages phone book.  The reason for this is to update any old contact information stored in my database with more recent relevant contact information.  So far i've only come across Whitepages Pro that offers an API that will allow for me to run some queries against their database and return what I assume is the most up to date information.
I have access to users phone numbers, name, and address and so the initial idea was to compare old phone numbers + name against the more up to date database to correct the old data.
My question is, does this seem like a good solution for my problem?  Whitepages seems to be the only available tool for me to use (it does cost ~$300 but if it works then I am more than willing to spend the money), but if there are other options that people have tried i'd be willing to look into them as a possible solution.

Also, ive looked at [Alternative to WhitePages API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2448875/alternative-to-whitepages-api) as a similar post however the options given did not suite my needs.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can always build your own web crawler or use a company that provides a web crawler. https://import.io/